# Concerned about relays on Algorand

Tags: blockchain, algorand

I started blockchain dev with Algorand recently. Does anyone know if relays verify transactions before forwarding them to participation nodes? Worried about a smart contract call failing but being forwarded anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, transactions are verified first. They won't forward a transaction that they deem invalid - it would just get dropped.